# c:foreach inside h:datatable to show two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, jsf, jakarta-ee, foreach, datatable

I am trying to use h:datatable tag to display values of two-dimensional int array. But cannot make it. Could help me with a solution?

So my backing bean is:

```
public class MC {
...........

public int[][] getAr() {
    return ar;
}

public int getColCount(){
    return ar[0].length;
}
}
```

I can display the array with code in foreach tag referring to the array size:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{mC.ar}" var="dt">
<c:forEach var="fe" begin="0" end="#{mC.colCount-1}">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">X</f:facet>
            #{dt[fe]}
    </h:column>
</c:forEach> 
</h:dataTable>
```

But nothing is printed if I try to use variable from dataTable:

```
 <h:dataTable value="#{mC.ar}" var="dt">
 <c:forEach var="fe" items="#{dt}">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">XX</f:facet>
            #{fe}
    </h:column>
</c:forEach> 
</h:dataTable>
```

Could you help me to make it work? Or perhaps you could suggest some better solution to display an array? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is quite common mistake done in assumption that c:forEach is processed in the same time the iteration of dataTable is processed. c:forEach is processed once in build JSF tree, in this phase there is NO "dt" variable defined. h:dataTable defines the "dt" variable in JSF restore/render phases. Use the ui:repeat instead of c:forEach if you need to iterate in this phases.