# Column added in the forEach tag are not displayed

Tags: jsf, icefaces-3

I have a ace:dataTable which contains a variable number of columns. For this I use the c:forEach tag. All generated in the c:forEach are not displayed. In the sample, only columnLibelle and columnSum are displayed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
    xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/pages/layer/layout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <ice:form id="myForm">

                <h:panelGroup styleClass="table" layout="block">
                    <ace:dataTable id="myTable"
                        value="#{myBean.tableElements}"
                        var="currentElement" rowClasses="oddRow, evenRow" styleClass="tbl"
                        paginator="false">

                        <ace:column id="columnLibelle"
                            headerText="#{msg['common.libelle']}"
                            sortBy="#{currentElement.libelle}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{currentElement.libelle}" />
                        </ace:column>

                        <ace:column id="columnSum" headerText="#{msg['common.sum']}"
                            sortBy="#{currentElement.sum}">

                            <h:outputText value="#{currentElement.sum}">
                                <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="0" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </ace:column>

                        <c:forEach items="#{currentElement.services}" var="currentService">
                            <ace:column headerText="#{msg[currentElement[currentService.service.label]]}"
                                sortBy="#{msg[currentElement[currentService.service.label]]}">

                                <h:outputText value="#{currentElement[currentService.service.value]}">
                                    <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="0" />
                                </h:outputText>
                            </ace:column>
                        </c:forEach>

                    </ace:dataTable>
                </h:panelGroup>

            </ice:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688858/cforeach-inside-hdatatable-to-show-two-dimensional-array

Comment: ok thank you. i think it's the solution

Comment: the ui:repeat don't work. I have only one occurence and it's empty : no text in header and body, only the sort icone...